# Call to a member function query() only on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting this error only when I try connect to my localhost, but if i test on my web host, everything is running perfect.

The error i get is pointing on my `$query = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM video");`

```
<?php
    $query = $dbh->query("SELECT video_img FROM video");
        while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))   {

            echo $r->video_title;

        }

?>
```

db connection

```
<?php

$user   =   "root";
$pass   =   "";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=streaming', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from video') as $row) {
        //print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Any tips :)?

Thanks

Comment: Your `$dbh`, or `$query` is not an object. `var_dump` them.

Comment: You don't have anything in '$dbh' or not connected to db

Comment: @RamSharma The connection to the DB is working fine, I updated my question with the DB connection

Comment: Why do you have a query in your DB connection?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm just testing the connection

Comment: You are aware that you're setting `$dbh` to `null`, so any queries after that won't work, right...?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the codes you posted, `$dbh` doesn't make sense since no PDO connection has be initialized:

Second, you are selecting column `video_img`, then accessing/fetching `$r->video_title`. This doesn't make sense also:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE_NAME', 'username', 'password');
$query = $dbh->query("SELECT video_img FROM video");
while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))   {
    echo $r->video_img;
}
```

Comment: I just updated with my db connection.

And the selection video_img was my bad, I did not double check the query before I posted. corrected now.